# How can we add two different nested lists together?

Tags: python

if we have a nested list `ListA` and another nested list `ListB` of same length how can we add these nested lists replacing original values of `ListA` in Python? I browsed on hours on end, and found no reliable solution.

Would it be possible to do inside a for loop too? Optimally without NumPy, pure python.

Here's a pseudo code:

```
ListA = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

ListB = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Expected output: `ListA = [[6, 8], [10, 12]]`

because... 1 + 5, 2 + 8 etc...

Comment: you could convert to numpy arrays, then add using +

Comment: I forgot to mention, is this possible without numpy?

Comment: `[[*map(sum, zip(*items))] for items in zip(ListA, ListB)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `zip`:

```py
ListA = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
ListB = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]

output = [[x + y for x, y in zip(sublstA, sublstB)] for sublstA, sublstB in zip(ListA, ListB)]
print(output) # [[6, 8], [10, 12]]
```

Slight generalization:

```py
ListA = [[1, 2, 0], [3, 4]]
ListB = [[5, 6, 1], [7, 8]]
ListC = [[9, 0, 2], [1, 2]]

output = [[sum(nums) for nums in zip(*sublists)] for sublists in zip(ListA, ListB, ListC)]
print(output) # [[15, 8, 3], [11, 14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = [[a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]] for a, b in zip(ListA, ListB)]
```